# PhD offer: what to do after a long reflection pause?

Tags: phd, advisor, application

I have been offered a PhD position (to which I did not apply, it was from a professor who knows me). I am not entirely sure about accepting, but for various reasons I don't want to give a negative answer already.

It's been few weeks since the chat we had. It is expected that I give some kind of response to the professor. Some possibilities:

1. "I am still thinking about it": shows a lack of interest
2. not doing anything: unpolite and shows a lack of interest
3. asking more time to think: possibly shows a lack of interest

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

First, it is OK to be undecided.

I'd suggest that you say, in person, that you are flattered by the offer, but need to explore what other options you have and that you haven't yet had a chance to do that. That is also OK and doesn't show lack of interest. You can also spend a bit of time in conversation exploring the research topics you might explore with them. That shows interest and you might just come up with something that interests you.

But, I also suggest developing a plan to search out the options so that you have something to compare this offer with.

Comment: Is it very important the "in person"? I can only do emails or ask for teams meetings as of now...

Comment: Such things are much better done face to face. Nuance can be everything and it is lost in emails. But you use the tools you have.